# How to read JSON file and save data using Fetch API?

Tags: angular

I used Fetch Api to read JSON file and now I want to use data from JSON file in same function and in another function but for some reason I cant do both. This is my .ts file:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.objekat.length;i++)
      {
      fetch("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=RS&locality="+this.translate(this.objekat[i].grad)+"&addressLine="+this.translate(this.objekat[i].ulica)+"&o=json&key=AnEFyy5lm4z6A0DvrM73UrBRHFAA8HVKFp93EdmF7pC3foV-WzbsBKit5Xs4B2nv", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => this.LatLog(data, this.objekat[i].ulica, this.objekat[i].adresniBroj,     this.objekat[i].grad, this.korisnik.rola))
      .then(json => {
        this.results= json
        console.log(this.results);  
       })
      }
```

I want to use second and third .then but for some reason I can just use one depend which I put first in code.